# Webpack@4.41 with babel-loader@8 error while building react scripts (Module parse failed: Unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to implement webpack@4.41 and babel-loader@8 to process react scripts. I have troubles with bundling jsx syntax (webpack babel-loader exiting with error while encountering any html tags.

I use the command: `npm run build`  (webpack --mode production)

index.js

```
// Import the wrapper component, and the the creator function
import React  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <p> Hello React project</p>;
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Usual error message:

```
[0] ./src/index.js 339 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class App extends React.Component {
|   render () {
>     return <p> Hello React project</p>;
|   }
| }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! webpack_test@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Bundling also fails constantly when trying to do: `render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));`  after importing App component from another file or defining App function which renders html tags.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

package.json

```
  "name": "webpack_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
  }
}
```

I tried bundling the index.js  file with `@babel/cli` , which seems to work (command `npx babel --presets @babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react` ). I have been trying to solve this for too long now, and I would really appreciate some pointers :) Thanks for help,

**UPDATE**
`webpack.config.js` had a trailing space, so it was not recognized by webpack.

Answer (score 1):

You can check my config

My webpack

```
{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
},
```

.babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
```

Update:

Make sure to install `"eslint": "^6.8.0"` to your package.json in devDependencies section

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried updating webpack rules to: use: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"], installed 
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
"eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",

and edited .babelrc to: 
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ]
}

with the error persisting, unfortunately...

Comment: Can you share your full code on github ? I will have a look

Comment: Here is the frontend application, https://github.com/rmilosic/mojkredit.si/tree/dev/client

Comment: I can build your code without any problem. Check my answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208800/discussion-between-rmilosic-and-tony-ngo).

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using? And are you using npm or yarn?

Comment: Just clone your repo and install eslint nothing more

Comment: Issue was resolved, there was a trailing space in the name of webpack.config.js, so the webpack.config.sj file was not being recognised. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Warning on eslint-loader: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin